# Как протестировать игровой сервер на глобальной сети

Tags: c++, windows, сервер, разработка-игр

Я разрабатываю игровой сервер для своей игры и хочу протестировать его  на глобальной сети, чтобы я мог запустить у себя сервер и попросить друга подключиться к нему. Слышал о ngrok но он не подходит так как у меня протокол UDP, который ngrok не поддерживает. Значит, как я понимаю нужно открыть нужный порт, к примеру 22005 и сделать статический ip и тогда если я скину другу свой ip и порт то он сможет подключиться или нужно сделать что-то еще? Может можно поднять сервер на nginx или apache, но как тогда это сделать, практически все материалы посвящены по развертыванию сайтов а не игровых серверов. В общем жду любых советов

Comment: да UDP, Windows, C++, библиотека enet

Comment: точно, hamachi должно помочь, как-то я забыл про него, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня аналогичный сервер под Windows написан на Delphi. Просто запускаю exe и все становится доступным (по IP и порту). Вот достать внешний IP - сложно. Тут или хостинг покупать, или у провайдера как услугу. Для тестов, можно попробовать **через Hamachi** настроить подсеть, там все IP будут как надо.